# Pinning TensorFlow OpKernels to specific cores

Tags: tensorflow

I have written an `OpKernel` that is expensive and stateful. Using the default implementation of Eigen's NonBlockingThreadPool and the standard scheduling in this threadpool implementation means that

- OpKernels are run on any available thread/core
- State for this op must be transferred to the new core, which causes non-optimal cache behavior

Is there a way to pin expensive ops to run on specific cores?

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible, but you're not the first person to have a similar need.